# All Undefined Results

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

Please tell me if this select statement looks wrong to you. For some reason, every selection in the drop-down reads undefined instead of the username.

**View**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="filteredUserId" ng-options="users.Id as users.Username for user in users"></select>
```

**Controller**

```
dmUser.GetUsers().then((response) =>
{
    $scope.users = response.data;
});
```

I verified in Postman what the results are. They are list of these kinds of objects:

```
{
    "Id": 123,
    "FirstName": "john",
    "LastName": "smith",
    "Username": "johnsmith",
    "EmailAddress": "johnsmith@test.com"
}
```

I also tried using the following and it actually works...

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="filteredUserId">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.Id}}">{{user.Username}}</option>
</select>
```

It's bugging me that the code using the ngOptions doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you are using `users` instead of `user` when accessing the properties in `ng-options`. It should be `ng-options="user.Id as user.Username for user in users"`